# Replace repeated characters regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am newbie in regular expression.

I want to replace repeated characters from my string. here some example

```
$str1 = "aaa bbb cc dddd";  // output : a b c d

$str2 = "Google is the best";  // output : Google is the best
```

I found lots of question related this question on stackoverflow. But it does not satisfy my requirement.

I tried this `(\w)\1` but this is not my solution

Any idea ? Thanks in advance

Edit :

More examples

```
 $str1 = "this is tesaaat. are you ook?";  // output : this is tesaaat. are you ook?

 $str2 = "Good morning mmmm yyyy friendssss ";  // output : Good morning m y friends

 $str3 = "Hello friendd okk";  // output : Hello friend okk
```

Inshort I want to replace repeted charactor followed by space only.

Comment: Please explain why the oo in Google are not repeating characters.

Comment: @ceving  I want to replace repeted charactor followed by space only.

Comment: As well as the 'oo' in 'Good'

Comment: @rawb I have diplayed output after that string

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following regex: `\b(\w)\1+\b`.

Explanation:

- A word break (`\b`)
- A single character
- The repetition (at least one time the same character)
- Again, a word break

**EDIT:** With more details, I would say you can get rid of the first `\b`. So, it becomes: `(\w)\1+\b`

Comment: This is ok. but please refere question again. I added more clear example.

Comment: Answer edited, but still don't understand why `This is a tesaaaat.` => `This is a tesat.`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Ouput should be "This is a tesaaaat." Inshort I want to replace repeted charactor followed by space only.

Answer (score 3):

Following regex would work for all letters in any language with `u`-unicode flag:

```
/([\p{L}\W])\1+(?= )/u
```

*Explanations:*

```
(                 # beginning of 1st capturing group
    [             # beginning of characters class
        \p{L}     # any letter from any language
        \W        # any non-word character
    ]             # end of character class
)                 # end of 1st capturing group
\1                # back reference to our 1st capturing group for repetition
+                 # one or more character repetition
(?= )             # using positive lookahead to be sure it's followed by a space
```

Using `preg_replace` to achieve the job:

```
$string = preg_replace("/([\p{L}\W])\1+(?= )/u", "$1", $string);
```

Output for your examples:

```
"aaa bbb cc dddd "  =>  "a b c d "
"Google is the best"  =>  "Google is the best"
"this is tesaaat. are you ook?"  =>  "this is tesaaat. are you ook?"
"Good morning mmmm yyyy friendssss "  =>  "Good morning m y friends "
"Hello friendd okk"  =>  "Hello friend okk"
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pY7hA9)

Comment: Can't +1 this answere for good explanation. But test this string "Google is the best" or "Hello friend". This is not working for me. Please refere question again. I want to replace repeted charactor followed by space only.

Comment: Note: the regular expression is not [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) any more.

Comment: the demo works fine but as i noticed unlike answer's regex in demo there are to modifiers - `u` and `g`. also in the demo the regex is `([\p{L}\s])\1+(?= )`, but in the answer `([\p{L}\W])\1+(?= )`. When I try to use the demo's version with midifier `g` I get an error `Unknown modifier 'g'`, if  I remove it, the regex does not work. thanks

Comment: @dav `preg_replace` would work as intended without `g` modifier **But** for matching you should use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = "aaa bbb cc dddd";
$replacedText = preg_replace('{(\w)\1+}','$1',$text);
```

if you don't want repetitive whitespaces as well, try the following:

```
$replacedText = preg_replace('{(.)\1+}','$1',$text);
```

Comment: The following is ugly but works for Google:

`$replacedText = preg_replace(array('/(.)\1+/', '/Gogle/'), array('$1', 'Google'), $text);`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
preg_replace('/(\b)(\w)\2+(\b)/', '$2', $string);
```